# Function to increment each letter's ASCII value in a string only returns one letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, tostring

Using JavaScript I have written a function to loop through a given string and increment each letter value and return the new string. Here is what my code looks like:

```
function alphabeticShift(inputString) {
  for (var i = 0; i <inputString.length; i++){
    var newString = []
    newString.push(String.fromCharCode(inputString.charCodeAt(i) + 1))

  }
  return newString.toString()
}

alphabeticShift('abc')
```

For some reason, the function only returns the very last letter of the string incremented. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: `const f = s => s.replace(/./g, m => String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt(0) + 1));`

Comment: The `newString` array should be outside of the loop. Right now you are creating a new array for each letter and so when you return only the array with the last letter is returned as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-initializing the array at every iteration. move the `var newString = []` line to outside of the loop

Also use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead of [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) as the later would insert commas

```js
function alphabeticShift(inputString) {
  var newString = []
  for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
    newString.push(String.fromCharCode(inputString.charCodeAt(i) + 1))

  }
  return newString.join("")
}

console.log(alphabeticShift('abc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

As Tibebes has mentioned you are reinitializing the array in each iteration in your loop.

### Alternative to Array Solution

Here is a solution using String concatenation instead of arrays.

```js
function alphabeticShift(inputString) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = 0; i <inputString.length; i++){
    
    newString += (String.fromCharCode(inputString.charCodeAt(i) + 1))

  }
  return newString;
}

const res = alphabeticShift('abc')

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6

```js
const alphabeticShift = str => [...str]
  .map(char => String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0)+1))
  .join('');

const res = alphabeticShift('abc')
console.log(res);
```